# INVALID OBJECT NAME 'Student'

Tags: sql-server

[Here's the pic of the sql server window.It is showing an error that the Table 'Student' doesn't exists.You can see in the pic that there is a database named as 'School1' and there exists the table 'Student'.
Any help will be appreciated....
THANKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkHGp.jpg)

Comment: You are in the *master* database not *school1* change the current db in the top-left dropdown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"master: database does not have this table. Change a database for your connection to "School1" Please check the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much sir..

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
USE [School1]
GO

Select * from Student
```

Answer (score 2):

Link only question are not appreciated, give as much information as you like, as text.

Your immediate problem is you don't tell sql server where to look for the object.

```
SELECT    *
FROM      School1.dbo.Student
```